# Android studio setup Error latest version

Tags: android, android-studio

i installed android studion latest version but it is giving this error any suggestion

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from 'C:\Users\BellComputer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aidl.exe'

Comment: Welcome! Although questions about programming tools (such as Android Studio) are on-topic for Stack Overflow, you've provided very little detail with which people can help you out. For example, at minimum you could edit your question to include what operating system and version you're running, at what stage the above error occurs, what you've already tried to fix the problem, and anything else you think might help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Enter SDK Tools from Android Studio (Blue down arrow with little Android on it) menu. Go to the SDK Tools tab and check "Show Package Details" checkbox below, you should see "Android SDK Build-tools" in the list expand it and uncheck if 26.0.2 is already checked. Then click "Apply". It will remove existing 26.0.2 build tools then check 26.0.2 again from list and click "Apply" it will reinstall build tools again. You can build your Android applications now.